How to remote control GIT
I'm a total newbie to GIT.
Right now we are using Team Foundation Server (TFS) as our version control system. We have written tools (.NET) for special tasks that use the TFS API to get the newest files, check them out, change them, check them in and so on (including error handling).
Now we want to (have to) switch to GIT.
Of cource we could just construct the necessary command line and Process.Start it. But that way it could be hard to catch different errors, since errors would probably sent to the console, and we don't want to catch the console output and try to parse it to find out which error occured.
So, is there some kind of API to remote control GIT? Or do you have other suggestions to automate certain parts of the GIT experience?
In case it matters: We need to get the most current files ('Get Latest Version' in TFS) and check some of them out (as far as I'm already learned not necessary in GIT). Then we change them automatically, after that the new files have to be checked in again (probably staged and committed in GIT).
I don't want to know the necessary GIT commands to do that, I just want to know, if there's an API that can be used programmatically that would make it easy to catch errors without parsing the console output or something like that.

Use a library, like libgit2

@perivesta: Thank you, I'll have a look into that.

git, being a distributed version control system, does not need "remote control" as it is a completely different paradigm to a centralised VCS. Eg. to get latest files in your copy of a repo from a remote just git fetch, but this won't update your working tree, to do that merge the remote tracking branch to your working branch (all of which are simple command line or GUI operations).

Don't start with automation, start learning the CLI (ie. do all git operations from the CLI) and learn git (don't convert: treat as new), work through the learning curve. The assumptions from your current approach will be your problem, you have more to unlearn than un-lean.
I went through this, the free Pre Git is good. You will need to invest time.
